# Перестает видеть файл после внесения изменений в коде

Tags: python, python-3.x, файлы, файловая-система

Создаю новый файл с кодом

```
str = input('Input text here')
str += "\n"

file = open('data/t.txt', 'w')
file.write(str)
file.close()
```

Все работает хорошо, проверяю папку data - файл есть. Далее меняю w на a, чтобы дозаписать что-то в файл и выдает ошибку  "[Errno 2] No such file or directory". Снова меняю на w - тоже не работает. Пробовала прописывать путь по-разному, в том числе абсолютный путь. Получается точно также. Когда создаешь новый файл с кодом - тоже создает текстовый файл и код перестает работать. Папка находится не на диске С.
Скажите, пожалуйста, в чем может быть проблема?

Comment: Приведите код, позволяющий воспроизвести проблему.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Указывая

> **не** на диске C

Вы имели ввиду расшареный диск?

В любом случае, проблема скорее всего с хитро указанными правами доступа. При этом Вы можете создавать файлы, но не можете их модифицировать.

Попробуйте запустить:

```
icacls data
```

и проверьте ваши права доступа.

[Здесь](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/windows/it-pro/windows-server-2012-R2-and-2012/cc753525(v=ws.11)) можно почитать про icacls.

Comment: В моем случае помогло запускать консоль от имени администратора, тогда код начинает работать. Спасибо.